# No response from Knowledge Base in Dialogflow

Tags: nlp, bots, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to make Frequently asked questions and answers bot in dialogflow.  I have Q&A files, so I am used knowledge base in dialogflow .i have the 6-7 file i make documents in the knowledge base. but when i ask question bot not sending any response.

[Image of knowledge base console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n5WA.png)

[Knowledge Base Document QNA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evS2l.png)

[dialogflow text response screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLHY1.png)

Comment: its still missing response section where you have added `$Knowledge.Answer[1]`, please add that as well.

Comment: there is a default response in all the screenshots, is there any intent with similar training phrase from where this response might come? you can check `diagnostic info` as well

Answer (score 4):

In the response section you need to give `$Knowledge.Answer[1]`.

[image: knowledge response]

Comment: ,yes i saw your added image but unfortunately its not working still i get default intent response...

Answer (score 3):

- **If you can't get answer in your App** knowledge connectors won't work with the production SDK for now, you have to use the Beta SDK/API and pass QueryParameters object for the knowledge connector when you use `detect_intent` function.
  check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/knowledge-connectors#detect-intent-python)
- **If you can't get answer in the portal** you need to adjust `KNOWLEDGE RESULTS PREFERENCE` to be stronger and lower `ML CLASSIFICATION THRESHOLD` otherwise the `default fallback intent` gonna always answer. check the pictures below to see how to:

  [image]

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

The error might just be because you didn't enable the knowledge base

[image: Follow these instructions]

[image: Enable the knowledge base]

[image: click enable]

[image: enable response --> $Knowledge.Answer[1]]